# How can I fix the routing in my dashboard so it navigates to the correct page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using React JS and am trying to create a basic login/dashboard system that has a navbar on the side. I have encapsulated the login and dashboard pages into separate components as seen in my App.js file.

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/login/Login';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/Dashboard';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default App;
```

When a login is successful I navigate to /dashboard, which is my Dashboard component. In my Dashboard component I have routes that navigate to different pages, which are rendered in the Navbar component.

```
// Navbar.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { SidebarData } from './NavbarData';
import './Navbar.css';
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';

function Navbar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#fff' }}>
        <div className='navbar'>
          <Link to='#' className='menu-bars'>
            <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar} />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
          <ul className='nav-menu-items' onClick={showSidebar}>
            <li className='navbar-toggle'>
              <Link to='#' className='menu-bars'>
                <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose />
              </Link>
            </li>
            {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
                    {item.icon}
                    <span>{item.title}</span>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

```
// NavbarData.js
import React from 'react';
import { FaUser, FaHome, FaAddressBook, FaList, FaInfoCircle, FaEllipsisH } from "react-icons/fa";

export const SidebarData = [
  {
    title: 'Profile',
    path: '/profile',
    icon: <FaUser />,
    cName: 'nav-text'
  },
  {
    title: 'Home',
    path: '/home',
    icon: <FaHome />,
    cName: 'nav-text'
  },
  {
    title: 'Contacts',
    path: '/contacts',
    icon: <FaAddressBook />,
    cName: 'nav-text'
  },
  {
    title: 'Codes',
    path: '/codes',
    icon: <FaList />,
    cName: 'nav-text'
  },
  {
    title: 'System Information',
    path: '/sysinfo',
    icon: <FaInfoCircle />,
    cName: 'nav-text'
  },
  {
    title: 'More',
    path: '/more',
    icon: <FaEllipsisH />,
    cName: 'nav-text'
  },
];
```

```
// Dashboard.js
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from '../navbar/Navbar';
import Profile from '../../screens/Profile';
import Home from '../../screens/Home';
import Contacts from '../../screens/Contacts';
import Codes from '../../screens/Codes';
import SysInfo from '../../screens/SysInfo';
import More from '../../screens/More';

export default function Dashboard() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
                <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
                <Route path='/contacts' element={<Contacts />} />
                <Route path='/codes' element={<Codes />} />
                <Route path='/sysinfo' element={<SysInfo />} />
                <Route path='/more' element={<More />} />
                
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
}
```

After I login I can see the dashboard and my Navbar but when I try clicking on the links in the Navbar I get a blank page. From what I can see I am only rendering one Dashboard component which does not route properly when I click the links in my Navbar. I want to be able to route to different screens.

Comment: _"I get a blank page"_... check your browser console for errors

Comment: Check the URL to see if `/dashboard/{path}` is correct.

Comment: @GregFenton When a routed component, i.e. `Dashboard`, renders another `Routes` and set of `Route` components, these are known as descendent routes. It's a different concept from nested routes where a `Route` directly renders another `Route` component.

Comment: [Descendent Routes](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-descendant-routes/) -- another not-so-well documented React Router concept.  Unless you call [a non-indexed, single-mention on a handful of pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=descendant+site%3Areactrouter.com) to be good documentation for an entire concept...

Thanks @DrewReese!

Comment: @GregFenton The React-Router v6 documentation is a ***very living*** document, and v6 has been quite turbulent in terms of features. It was in beta for a long time, and very much still has that feel after official release well over a year ago. FWIW an earlier version of their "Main Concepts" section included these more prominently.